# non-root access to physical blocks occupied by a file

Tags: filesystems, c, io

`ioctl()` and `FIBMAP` can be used to determine the physical blocks occupied by a file, given logical blocks obtainable via `stat()`; however, root access is required. Why is root access necessary for ascertainment of the disk location of a file, and are there any non-root-requiring mechanisms for obtaining the same information? For the use case that motivates this question, the files are small (about 1 block on average) so knowledge of the physical location of the first block alone would suffice (indirect blocks are certainly unnecessary). On the order of 100,000 such files must be accessed in short order (as fast as possible), and I would like to pre-sort based on disk location before delivery to the I/O scheduler's queue. Sorting by `inode` is a possibility that does not require root privileges, but the degree of correspondence between inode number and disk location is probabilistic, implying variation of performance with the strength of that correspondence.

Comment: Can you use FIEMAP instead? It was added some time during the 2.6.x series.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Thanks for pointing out `FIEMAP`; it does appear to satisfy my requirements.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Wouldn't that be an answer then?

Comment: @Fabby It would be an answer to just one of the two questions OP asked.

Comment: I am close to tracking down an answer to the "why" question. https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/11/22/163

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Nice find. I didn't manage to come across that mailing list posting in my own searches.